# How to take a user input that has two parts separated by commas and put them into different lists

Tags: python

I'm asking the user to type in an input that's separated by a comma (ex: Math, 30) and basically what I want to do is take "Math" and put that into one list and then take "30" and put that into another list.

Comment: `str.split` https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a,b=input().split(',')
a=[a]
b=[b]
print(a)
print(b)
```

So if input is Math,30
Output is 
['Math']
[30]

Comment: This answer actually provides the output the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with split():

```
data = "Math, 30".split(', ') # where the contents of split() are the characters you want to split
```

`data` is:

```
['Math','30']
```

You can then put this in your 2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows. You take your string as input, then use `string.split` on, further removing whitespaces around each word

```
string = input("Provide your string>>>")
list = [s.strip() for s in string.split(',')]
print(list)
#Provide your string>>>Math, 30
#['Math', '30']
```